# Is there a way to retrieve the Bundle Seed ID of an app at runtime?

Tags: iphone, app-store, bundle, nsbundle

I am developing two apps that use the Keychain to share data between them, and this currently requires hardcoding the Bundle Seed ID to access the keychain. However, this is quite brittle, because the seed changes depending on how the app is signed. Is there way to determine the seed ID at runtime?